# Using subversion and git at the same time

Tags: git, svn, version-control, gitlab

In my little firm, I have been using subversion for over 5 years. I am using VisualSVN Server Manager for managing repos and tortoiseSVN in user's computer to commit, update etc.

I want to keep this as it is now. Along with that, I want to create copies of these repositories in gitlab.com under my account. What I want is as follows,

1. User commits to a repo from their computer
2. The commit is received by VisualSVN as it is
3. The commit also propagates as 'push' to respective online gitlab.com repo

Again, when I make changes in the gitlab repo and users do TortoiseSVN->Update they receive that update though they are not connected gitlab, they are still connected to subversion but the subversion is connected to gitlab.com repo

Is this possible?
Can anyone come up with a detailed plan to do this?

The reasons I want to do this are as follows,

1. I do not want my users to access the repo from out of office
2. I want to keep all the commits to hundreds of my svn repos as it is in new gitlab repos
3. I actually want to be safe (yeah, right, online isn't safe either, but it will work as a backup also, I guess) as the local-server's hard-disk is getting old

Comment: Did you have a look at the [official gitlab documentation for migration from SVN to gitl(lab)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/svn.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, but there are lot to read and my system is windows based but tutorials are mostly linux based. At this point, can you at least confirm that subgit can solve my problem, just the way I want it to be solved?

Comment: As per the overview it's meant to keep SVN and git repos in sync which is what you describe. Subgit is Java based so you will be able to run it. You will have to dig into the subgit licensing to figure out whenever you can afford it or not and configure it accordingly and tailor it to your needs.